# vkCmdPipelineBarrier(): Image barrier 0x0x7fff9c1cdaf0 newLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL is not compatible with image 0x4 usage flags

Tags: linux, rendering, render, vulkan

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(): Image barrier 0x0x7fff9c1cdaf0 newLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL is not compatible with image 0x4 usage flags 0x16.

I'm trying to save the swapchain image to a picture file like png or bmp, and I found there is a sample in the Vulkan SDK 1.2.148.1, the path is : "VulkanSDK/1.2.148.1/ubuntu/samples/API-Samples/15-draw_cube", and it use a write_ppm function in the file "VulkanSDK/1.2.148.1/ubuntu/samples/API-Samples/utils/util.cpp", and the official sample runs very well.But when I use the function with same way, I passed a pre-constructed sample_info object into the write_ppm() function, and when it runs to the 2nd set_image_layout() function before the line "VkImageCopy copy_region;", and it give an error :

LOG:  VulkanDebugCallBack                     :40   ERROR: [Validation] Code 0 :  [ VUID-VkImageMemoryBarrier-oldLayout-01212 ] Object: 0x4 (Type = 10) | vkCmdPipelineBarrier(): Image barrier 0x0x7fff9c1cdaf0 newLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL is not compatible with image 0x4 usage flags 0x16. The Vulkan spec states: If either oldLayout or newLayout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL then image must have been created with VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT set (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImageMemoryBarrier-oldLayout-01212)
LOG:  VulkanDebugCallBack                     :40   ERROR: [Validation] Code 0 :  [ VUID-vkCmdCopyImage-srcImage-00126 ] Object: 0x4 (Type = 10) | Invalid usage flag for Image 0x4 used by vkCmdCopyImage(). In this case, Image should have VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT set during creation. The Vulkan spec states: srcImage must have been created with VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT usage flag (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdCopyImage-srcImage-00126)
formatNumByDigit() : num == 1, outputStr == 00001
utils::write_png() : Create a mappable image
LOG:  VulkanDebugCallBack                     :40   ERROR: [Validation] Code 0 :  [ VUID-vkBeginCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00049 ] Object: 0x5590939c7538 (Type = 6) | vkBeginCommandBuffer(): Cannot call Begin on command buffer (0x5590939c7538) in the RECORDING state. Must first call vkEndCommandBuffer(). The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the recording or pending state. (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkBeginCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00049)

It says "If either oldLayout or newLayout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL then image must have been created with VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT", but the image it's using is the very swapchain image, as I know it can be only aquired with the function vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(), how could I make sure if it was created with "VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT"? or, how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could I make sure if it was created with "VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT"?

You don't. Swapchain images don't belong to you; they belong to the display system and the OS. You are permitted to *use* them, but only in ways that the display system *allows*.

`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` tells you what the properties of swapchain images will be, including the image usage flags on them. The only usage flag that the Vulkan specification *requires* on swapchain images is the color attachment flag. Anything else, even a simple copy operation, is subject to the approval of the display system.

So if you want your application to be able to run on a variety of hardware, you need to take into account the possibility that you cannot copy from the swapchain image. As such, you need to at least be able to render to your own image, which you will eventually either blit to the swapchain image (which is again *not* required to be allowed) or render the image to the swapchain image.

Comment: Much appreciated! Sorry for checking this page so late!